# Using Ninject With Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ninject

I have a repository Class which takes in a ObjectContext called "TestDB". I when I launch my web application i'm getting a "Unable to load the specified metadate resource", almost like its not picking up the connection settings from my web.config file anymore.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
[Inject]
public SqlCatelogRepository(){
   _dataContext = new SQLDb(); 
   //EF Entity, should pickup connection settings from web.config
}
```

Once get what is going on there I would like to pass in my DataContenxt but I can't seem to wrap my head around how this should look in the Ninject Mapping.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245517/ninject-binding

Comment: Can you update your question with more code (e.g. Ninject Mapping / SqlCateglogRepository class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
[Inject]
public SqlCatelogRepository(){
   _dataContext = kernel.Get<SQLDb>(); 
   //EF Entity, should pickup connection settings from web.config
}
```

This will give NInject a chance to intercept your activation.  Then your mappings can apply.

You might want to check out the "Service Locator" approach that Nate wrote about: [http://kohari.org/2008/06/18/playing-nice-with-service-locators](http://kohari.org/2008/06/18/playing-nice-with-service-locators/)