# Using Generic Types while binding with Ninject - is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ninject

Using Ninject, in my main program I call:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyBindings());
var stuff = kernel.Get<MediaPresenter>();
```

Unfortunately I get an exception:

> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not
>   self-bindable.

I really don't understand what that means. Here is my binding class:

```
class MyBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<MediaPresenter>().ToSelf();
        Bind(typeof (Dao<Book>)).To(typeof (Dao<Book>));
    }
}
```

If I remove the line:

```
Bind(typeof(Dao<Book>)).To(typeof(Dao<Book>));
```

The application runs, but then I get no bindings.

Why does that kind of thing not work and how can I fix it?

Comment: Oh sorry - forgot that. Yes, it's c#.

Comment: I've tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: Thx for tagging accordingly. I am also new to this site - so I please you to be appreciative of me :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't test it right now but this should work:

```
Bind(typeof (Dao<>)).To(typeof(Dao<>));
```

Using an interface, a probably better idea going forward:

```
Bind(typeof (IDao<>)).To(typeof(Dao<>));
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't do this in load :

```
Bind<Dao<Book>>.ToSelf();
```

Comment: I will explain it in my next answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be codding against interface as it will make your code alot more testable. Have a look at this more info on Ninject binding

[Ninject Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245517/ninject-binding)

ok in your case you need to do this (not tested). As long as you tell Inject the concrete implmentations it will take care of the injection at the right places for you depending that you have the right inject attributes in place in your code.

```
  class MyBindings : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void Load()
            {
                Bind<IMediaPresenter>().To<MediaPresenter>;
                Bind<IDao>().To<Dao>();
                Bind<IBook>().To<Book>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that's where I came from :(

First my code looked like this:

Bind<IDao<Book>>().To<Dao<Book>>();

But as I saw, that this won't work, I started debugging my code. So - finally I got that what I posted at first.

Whatever I did, the error is still the same.

Comment: I tried your solution too - but even that does not work. If I try so, I will get a compiler error: "Fehler 1 Using the generic type 'SessionPerPresenter.Data.IDao<TEntity>' requires '1' type arguments D:\...blah...\SessionPerPresenter\Program.cs 67 18 SessionPerPresenter
"

Comment: the only way we can help you is if you post some code. Will that be possible so I can replicate it on my site.

Comment: Of course it is possible - I will post it in a few minutes :)

Comment: GOT IT!

Thanks guys - you showed me the right way, but I was almost blind :) Here is what I found out:

My DAO-class has an constructor with one parameter

 public Dao(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)

As I am new to Ninject, I forgot that and did not bind that 'sessionfactory'. After binding it, everything works fine.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Stefan

Comment: Great new Stefan. Glad we could help